# Matlab's contour and colormap ignores input values

Tags: matlab, plot, contour, colormap

I'm plotting a contour using the contourf function in Matlab and using sound pressure levels and the associated coordinates as an input. The maximum SPL is over 78 dB.
The contourf function somehow is only taking values until 75 dB into account but I need a finer resolution what is covering values until the maximum one. Now all values over 75 dB are in the same color.

[image: Click for wrong colormap]

```
                    % Plotting
                    figure();
                    contourf(xObsGnewGrid,yObsGnewGrid,obsSplMaxInterp,'LineColor','none');
                    axis equal;
                    clrb = colorbar('eastoutside','Ticks',[0:2:100]);
                    zlab = get(clrb,'ylabel');
                    set(zlab,'String','SPL [dBA]');
                    ylabel('Lateral Position [m]');
                    xlabel('Longitudinal Position [m]');
                    xlabel('Longitudinal Position [m]');
```

Comment: What happens if you just increase the number of contour levels?

Comment: Thanks! It worked :)!

Comment: Use a different colormap if you want any reasonable visual information. #deathtojet

Comment: Which would you recommend?